# How to sort multiD array by int

Tags: php

**How can I sort the whole data array by score with the same group of value**

**Like if I input data:**

Name: Stud1 -
Score: 150

Name: Stud2 -
Score: 120

Name: Stud3 -
Score: 200

**I want an output**

Name: Stud3 -
Score: 200

Name: Stud1 -
Score: 150

Name: Stud2 -
Score: 120

```
<?php
$tot = readline("Enter Total Students: ");

$data = array(
    $name = array(),
    $score = array(),
);

$eng_mark = array();
$math_mark = array();
$comp_mark = array();


for($i=0; $i<$tot; $i++){
    $name = readline("Enter Student Name: ");
    $eng_mark[$i]= readline("Enter English Mark: ");
    $math_mark[$i] = readline("Enter Math Mark: ");
    $comp_mark[$i]= readline("Enter Computer Mark: ");
    $score = $eng_mark[$i] + $math_mark[$i] + $comp_mark[$i];
}
```

?>

Comment: What does the array look like?

Comment: @Andreas should have name and its score sir

Comment: Include the array in your question! We can't answer if we don't know what your array looks like

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your input array looks like:

```
$ar = array('Stud1' => 
                    array('Score' => 150),
            'Stud2' => 
                    array('Score' => 120),
            'Stud3' => 
                    array('Score' => 200),
            );
```

You can try to create it with:

```
$data = [];
for($i=0; $i<$tot; $i++){
    $name = readline("Enter Student Name: ");
$data[$name] = [];
    $eng_mark[$i]= readline("Enter English Mark: ");
    $math_mark[$i] = readline("Enter Math Mark: ");
    $comp_mark[$i]= readline("Enter Computer Mark: ");
    $score = $eng_mark[$i] + $math_mark[$i] + $comp_mark[$i];
$data[$name] = $score;
}
```

Then you can use [arsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) function and get [desired output](https://3v4l.org/qHi6A):

```
Array
(
    [Stud3] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 200
        )
    [Stud1] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 150
        )
    [Stud2] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 120
        )
)
```

Comment: How do you know the array looks like that? Don't guess answer

Comment: I'd suggested the way how to make it, a little changing of the OP `for` loop.

Comment: By answering unclear questions you promote poor quality questions. Wait for OP to post a good question before answering the question.

Comment: So why does the question have two downvotes and four close votes then?

Comment: I'll advise you to post a question on meta and see what others think. Is this a question that is suitable for SO or not.

Comment: Im sorry sir @Andreas I am really new in programming and we have some case study to make and I really can't get how array in php work. I'll be better next time sir. Thankyou sir.

Comment: Thankyou sir @AksenP for the understanding sir. I tried it and it works. Im trying to analyze it so I can do it next time by myself.